# How to insert trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have two tables:

1. `users`
2. `trainer`

In the `users` table, I have a column `is_trainer=false` by default`.

When a user inputs the information in the table `users` and chooses the column `is_trainer=true` I want to insert the user information in the `trainer` table.

When I omit the if condition, after I insert a user in the `users` table it puts the information in the `trainer` table, but when I put if condition, it cannot work! I think it thinks that `is_trainer` is for the `trainer` table not for the `users` table

My code:

```sql
BEGIN
    IF NEW.is_trainer <> OLD.is_trainer THEN
        INSERT INTO trainer(trainer_id, sport_id, fee_per_hour, experience, created_by)
        VALUES(users.user_id, 3, '200$', 3, 6);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work as you expect:

```
IF NEW.is_trainer <> OLD.is_trainer THEN
```

In an `INSERT` trigger, there is not `OLD` value, ie all columns in pseudo table `OLD` are `NULL`. So your expression boils down to:

```
IF NEW.is_trainter <> NULL THEN
```

This condition can never be true, since nothing is different that `NULL`, nor equal to `NULL` (to check for nullness, you need `IS NULL`).

Based on your description of your requirement, I think that you want:

```
IF NEW.is_traiter = true THEN
```

Also, your `INSERT` command will not work, since it is referencing unknown relation `users`. You probably want:

```
INSERT INTO trainer(trainer_id,sport_id,fee_per_hour,experience,created_by)
VALUES(NEW.user_id, 3, '200$', 3, 6);
```

Likely, other values that you are giving for insert into `trainer` should also come from pseudo-table `NEW` (such as `created_by` for example).

Comment: Just a small note. If, as implied, the column is_trainer is defined as boolean the construct "If new.is_trainer = true then" can be reduces to just "If new.is_trainer then".